# Google AppEngine - Cannot Allocate Memory Error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, kotlin, jar, google-cloud-platform

The *Jar* app hosted on Google AppEngine was receiving an out of memory error. Stopping the version and starting it again seemed to solve the issue temporarily, but does not explain the root of the issue. According to the logs there does not seem to be a specific segment of code causing the issue.

## Expected

*Jar* app runs logic to populate Firestore database based on a `TimerTask` continuously.

## Observed

**Error**

```
[

{
"textPayload": "#  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2643), pid=1, tid=0x00007f408a5ba700\n",
"insertId": "4t9c0fkq1x7u8j87f",
"resource": {
"type": "gae_app",
"labels": {
   "project_id": "coinverse-media-staging",
   "version_id": "media-staging-0205190312pm",
   "module_id": "default"
 }
},

"timestamp": "2019-04-27T15:22:17Z",
"labels": {
 "compute.googleapis.com/resource_name": "91f332caeaa0",
 "compute.googleapis.com/resource_id": "1199188591019602609",
 "compute.googleapis.com/zone": "us-central1-c",
 "appengine.googleapis.com/instance_name": "aef-default-media--staging--0205190312pm-129n"
},

"logName": "projects/coinverse-media-staging/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Fstdout",
"receiveTimestamp": "2019-04-27T15:22:21.994076321Z"
}
]
```

**Warning**

```
[
{
"textPayload": "OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000e1400000, 515899392, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)\n",
"insertId": "4t9c0fkq1x7u8k14c",
"resource": {
 "type": "gae_app",
 "labels": {
   "project_id": "coinverse-media-staging",
   "version_id": "media-staging-0205190312pm",
   "module_id": "default"
 }
},

"timestamp": "2019-04-27T15:23:18Z",
"labels": {
 "appengine.googleapis.com/instance_name": "aef-default-media--staging--0205190312pm-129n",
 "compute.googleapis.com/resource_name": "91f332caeaa0",
 "compute.googleapis.com/resource_id": "1199188591019602609",
 "compute.googleapis.com/zone": "us-central1-c"
},
"logName": "projects/coinverse-media-staging/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Fstderr",
"receiveTimestamp": "2019-04-27T15:23:21.993115250Z"
}
```

## Libraries

*build.gradle*

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.20'
ext.junitJupiterVersion  = '5.3.2'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.3'
}
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.2.51'
}

version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '5.3.2'
    // JUnit Jupiter API and TestEngine implementation
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitJupiterVersion}")
    testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitJupiterVersion}")
    testImplementation "org.assertj:assertj-core:3.11.1"
    // To avoid compiler warnings about @API annotations in JUnit code
    testCompileOnly 'org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.5.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.56.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev206-1.25.0'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```